# Can I use lambda to create a query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to implement a function that takes a lambda as the argument and queries the database. I use SQLAlchemy for ORM. Is there a way to pass the lambda, that my function receives, to SQLAlchemy to create a query?

Sincerely,
Roman Prykhodchenko

Comment: Could you provide example of desired result? Its not too clear from the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to filter the data with the lambda, like a WHERE clause? Well, no, functions nor lambdas cannot be turned into a SQL query. Sure, you could just fetch *all* the data and filter it in Python, but that completely defeats the purpose of the database.

You'll need to recreate the logic you put into the lambda with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did want to filter results with the lambda.